# how to set a flag / variable in xslt to enter if again (related to converting to Junit format)

Tags: xslt, variables, junit, parameters

I am reading an external log file via xslt, and i want to find a certain line.
Once i find it, i want to print all the lines until i hit another line.
i need to do this repeatedly for a very big log file.
each iteration has a unique id and the log file seperated relevant info by
"iteration number: X" till "iteration number X+1" (or EOF).

Here's my xsl: (the relevant code is in the failure tag)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <testsuites>        
            <xsl:variable name="buildName" select="//rest/*/test_name"/>    
            <xsl:variable name="numberOfTests" select="count(//rest/*/iter_num)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="numberOfFailures" select="count(//rest/*/status [.= 'Fail'])" />    
            <xsl:variable name="numberSkipped" select="count(//rest/*/status [.!='Pass' and .!='Fail'])" /> 
            <xsl:variable name="logfile" select="//rest/@logfile" />    
            <xsl:variable name="testfile" select="//rest/@testFile" />

            <testsuite name="QE AUTOMATION TESTS"
                tests="{$numberOfTests}" time="0"
                failures="{$numberOfFailures}"  errors="0"
                skipped="{$numberSkipped}">

                <xsl:for-each select="//rest/*">
                    <xsl:variable name="testName" select="test_name"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="executionId" select="iter_num"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="start_time" select="fn:replace(start_time,' ','T')" />
                    <xsl:variable name="end_time" select="fn:replace(end_time,' ','T')"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="test_parameters" select="test_parameters"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="test_positive" select="test_positive"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="time_diff" select="xs:dateTime($end_time)-xs:dateTime($start_time)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="duration_seconds" select="seconds-from-duration($time_diff)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="duration_minutes" select="minutes-from-duration($time_diff)"/>  
                    <xsl:variable name="duration_hours" select="hours-from-duration($time_diff)"/>      
                    <xsl:variable name="outcome" select="status"/>  
                    <xsl:variable name="message" select="$buildName"/>  
                                <testcase classname="qe-tests.{local-name(.)}"
                                    name="{$testName}"
                                    time="{$duration_hours*3600 + $duration_minutes*60 + $duration_seconds }">
<xsl:if test="contains($outcome, 'Fail')"> 
    <failure>
        <xsl:param name="executionEnd" select="$executionId +1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="postIterX" select="tokenize(.,concat('Iteration number: ',$executionId,'\r?\n'),'m')[2]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="inIterX" select="tokenize($postIterX, concat('\r?\n.*Iteration number: ',$executionEnd,'\r?\n?'),'m')[1]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$inIterX"/>  
    </failure>
</xsl:if>
                            </testcase>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuites>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i updated to code to use @empo solution but there is an error on using xsl:param in that way.

the log file i have is like this one (this is a simplified snippet)
(start at line "Iteration 70" and stop at Iteration 71" in this example)

```
2011-06-15 15:38:07,126 - networks - INFO - Compared entities are equal
2011-06-15 15:38:07,152 - rest-Main - INFO - Test status for iteration 60 Pass
2011-06-15 15:38:07,187 - rest-Main - INFO - Test name: add Network To Cluster
2011-06-15 15:38:07,192 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 70
2011-06-15 15:38:07,187 - rest-Main - INFO - Test action: addNetworkToCluster
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Run test: yes
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: TRUE
2011-06-15 15:38:07,152 - rest-Main - INFO - Test status for iteration 70 Fail
2011-06-15 15:38:07,192 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 71
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: DDDDD
 2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Run test: yes
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: TRUE

* EOF
```

the desired xml output looks like this: (the detailed output will be shown only on failure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <testsuite name="QE AUTOMATION TESTS" tests="2" time="0" failures="1" errors="0" skipped="0">
        <testcase classname="qe-tests.Network" name="Add Network to Cluster="3">
            <failure>
2011-06-15 15:38:05,674 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 70
2011-06-15 15:38:05,674 - rest-Main - INFO - Running function: networks.addNetworkToCluster
2011-06-15 15:38:05,675 - rest-Main - INFO - Running command: testStatus=addNetworkToCluster('TRUE',network='testrest1',cluster='RestCluster1')
2011-06-15 15:38:05,675 - networks - DEBUG - GET request content is --  url:http://localhost:8080/rhevm-api/networks 
2011-06-15 15:38:05,887 - networks - DEBUG - Response body for GET request is: &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Run test: yes
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: TRUE
</failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="qe-tests.network" name="Add network to iscsi" time="1"/>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

the origin xml looks like this: (snippet)
'Network' is just one possible child (there are more like 'Datacenters' for e.g.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rest logfile="log.txt" testFile="REST_API.ods">
    <Network>
        <test_parameters>name='RestDataCenter2',storage_type='iscsi',version='3.0'</test_parameters>
        <test_name>Add Network to cluster</test_name>
        <end_time>2011-06-13 01:22:56</end_time>
        <iter_num>70</iter_num>
        <test_positive>TRUE</test_positive>
        <tcms_test_case/>
        <start_time>2011-06-13 01:22:55</start_time>
        <status>Fail</status>
    </Network>
    <Network>
        <test_parameters>name='RestDataCenter2',storage_type='iscsi',version='3.0'</test_parameters>
        <test_name>Add network to iscsi</test_name>
        <end_time>2011-06-13 01:22:56</end_time>
        <iter_num>71</iter_num>
        <test_positive>TRUE</test_positive>
        <tcms_test_case/>
        <start_time>2011-06-13 01:22:55</start_time>
        <status>Pass</status>
    </Network>
</rest>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution. :)

Comment: +1 Good question. See my XSLT 2.0 answer based exclusively on `tokenize()`.

Comment: Is not clear to me the relation between the log flat text and the XML you have shown at the end. Moreover could you expand better "Once i find it, i want to print all the lines until i hit another line. i need to do this repeatedly for a very big log file. each iteration has a unique id and the log file seperated relevant info by "iteration number: X" till "iteration number X+1" (or EOF)."

Comment: @empo. The relation is as follows. the context is the xUnit plugin for jenkins that needs an XSL file in order to transform my custom XML to a junit XML. so the XSL does that.  the additional log file is a log file for the whole tests which prints out additional error messages that doesn't appear in the XML. the goal of the question was to tell the XSL, once a certain test fails, to find the right section of the log file and embed it in the output XML the XSL will create (under the <failure> tag).

Comment: @empo: the way the log file is formatted is by printing the "Iteration Number: X" that appears on the original XML.  so each iteration corresponds to a section in the XML (e.g. one <Network> node). and obisouly that last node will be terminated by EOF and not another "Iteration Number: X" line. i hope that clears the question more.

Comment: So, you need to manage two different files. The input XML and the log, right? For instance, when the input XML has `Network` with status fail, you want read the log at the related iteration number and put it in the final xml right? Your current XSLT is not accessing two different documents...

Comment: Change `xsl:param` to `xsl:variable` you don't need a parameter there. You also must be more clear about where the log content is; is it inside the input document or in an external file? I don't see any problem in the solution I have proposed.

Comment: the logfile is external and the original XML holds the path to it in the <rest logfile="logfile.txt"> attribute.  you don't need to manage anything. once the XSL file can read the XML & log file, the xUnit Plugin for jenkins will use it to create the new XML.

Comment: i changed the param to variable in the code but now it doesn't print the error log at all to the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Split the logfile into multiple logfiles before the xsl run.
  each log file will be named "logfile.txt-X" where X is the iteration number.
  now all you need to do is print the specific log file:

`<xsl:variable name="executionId" select="'70'"/>`

`<xsl:variable name="logfile" select="'logfile.txt'" />`

`<xsl:variable name="iter_log" select="concat($logfile,'-',$executionId)"/>`

`<xsl:variable name="output" select="unparsed-text($iter_log)">`

`<xsl:value-of select="$output" />`

what do you think?

Comment: Sure, especially if you're already doing some processing on the logfiles outside of XSLT.

Comment: i am. i think that this will be much easier on the disk/memory since the original log file is very big, and i would have to iterate it again on each failed test

Comment: I know it's not the best and clean solution, but its the only that solved my problem so far. i hope once i will know xsl better, i can revisit this question and implement on of the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this using for-each-group (or even Muenchian grouping with keys), and failed, since the population does not consist of nodes, and therefore so many of the useful operations aren't allowed.

The brute-force way to emulate a "normal coding" (i.e. procedural) loop is to use recursion. But to do that, you need to be able to use params. You would then "define a bool flag" by defining a boolean parameter, and passing a different value for it when you want to change it. Or better yet, when you want to stop printing out lines, just don't recurse.

Here is the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="2.0">
   <!-- $executionId is defined before and read from the xml, but for convenience: -->
   <xsl:variable name="executionId" select="'70'"/>
   <xsl:variable name="iter_line" select="concat('Iteration number: ',$executionId)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="logfile" select="'logfile.txt'" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($logfile), '\r?\n')" />
      <xsl:call-template name="search-for-start">
         <xsl:with-param name="remaining-lines" select="$lines"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- skip lines until we find one that matches the start pattern -->
   <xsl:template name="search-for-start">
      <xsl:param name="remaining-lines" select="()"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($remaining-lines[1], $iter_line)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$remaining-lines[1]"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="output-lines">
               <xsl:with-param name="remaining-lines" select="$remaining-lines[position() > 1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="search-for-start">
               <xsl:with-param name="remaining-lines" select="$remaining-lines[position() > 1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- output the given lines, up to the next 'Iteration number: ' -->
   <xsl:template name="output-lines">
      <xsl:param name="remaining-lines"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <!-- If so, we're done. -->
         <xsl:when test="contains($remaining-lines[1], 'Iteration number: ')" />
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$remaining-lines[1]"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="output-lines">
               <xsl:with-param name="remaining-lines" select="$remaining-lines[position() > 1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>            
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which, tested on your sample output, gives: (after the prolog)

```
2011-06-15 15:38:07,192 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 70
2011-06-15 15:38:07,187 - rest-Main - INFO - Test action: attachHostNic
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Run test: yes
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: TRUE
```

which I believe is the desired output.

This doesn't seem like a very elegant solution, but I don't know how else to do it when the items to be grouped are not nodes. Anybody else got ideas?

Comment: +1. Good answer. Even other solutions I think would rely on regex when treating with text.

Comment: I will give it a try. what about exporting the logic to an external script (python/bash/perl/js) if xslt supports it?

Comment: I've tackled this kind of problem in the past by wrapping each line of the unparsed-text() into an element so that a positional for-each-group can then be used. (XSLT 3.0 solves this by allowing patterns to match atomic values).

Comment: I thought of a better solution that will be more performance wise. why not split the log file before running the xsl into small files with names that correspond to the iteration number and that way you only need to print the right log file on failure.

Comment: @Michael: thanks, good idea. (Wrapping each item in an element.)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($logfile), '\r?\n')"/>
<xsl:variable name="start" select="f:find($lines 'Iteration 70')[1]"/>
<xsl:variable name="end" select="f:find($lines, 'Iteration 71')[1]"/>
<xsl:for-each select="subsequence($lines, $start, $end - $start + 1)">
   ...
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:function name="f:find" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="lines" as="xs:string*"/>
  <xsl:param name="content" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$lines">
     <xsl:if test="contains(., content)">
       <xsl:sequence select="position()"/>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: how do you make the xsl identify the f:find? xmlspy shouts on error.

Comment: Thank you ... I was trying to do something like this, but am not fluent enough in XPath 2.0 yet to have functions like `find` and `subsequence` in my back pocket.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLines" as="xs:string*" select=
  "tokenize(/, '\r?\n')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "for $x in my:procesStartStop($vLines,
                                 'Iteration number: 70',
                                 'Iteration number: 71')
     return ($x, '&#xA;')
   "
   />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:procesStartStop" as="xs:string*">
  <xsl:param name="pLines" as="xs:string*"/>
  <xsl:param name="pStart" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="pStop" as="xs:string"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "for $len in count(($pLines, $pStop)),
        $start in
           (for $i in 1 to $len
             return
                if(contains($pLines[$i], $pStart))
                  then $i
                  else()
            )
             [1],

        $end in
           (for $j in 1 to $len
             return
                if(contains($pLines[$j], $pStop))
                  then $j
                  else()
            )
             [1]

      return
        subsequence($pLines, $start, $end -$start +1)

   "/>
 </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (containing the provided text):

```
<t>
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,126 - networks - INFO - Compared entities are equal
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,152 - rest-Main - INFO - Test status for Pass
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,187 - rest-Main - INFO - Test name: Attach Host NIC To Network
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,192 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 70
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,187 - rest-Main - INFO - Test action: attachHostNic
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Run test: yes
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: TRUE
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,192 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 71
    2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: DDDDD
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct answer**:

```
 2011-06-15 15:38:07,192 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 70
 2011-06-15 15:38:07,187 - rest-Main - INFO - Test action: attachHostNic 
 2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Run test: yes 
 2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: TRUE 
 2011-06-15 15:38:07,192 - rest-Main - INFO - Iteration number: 71
```

Comment: wow, i think this is too complected for me. i think i will have hard time modifying it if i will have to in the future.

Comment: @Eyal I agree. I think it would be easier to read if you moved $len, $start, $end out of the for loop into normal XSLT variables.

Comment: It's definitely a good example of how to exploit the new iteration facility provided with XPath 2.0 :)) (+1)

Comment: @Dimitre, I'm curious why you used embedded `for` loops to populate $start and $end... could you not have used `find()`?

Comment: @LarsH: You know me -- I love providing a complete solution as a single XPath expression :)

Comment: @Eyal: It isn't hard to modify -- actually, it is very easy to pass a function as parameter (a la FXSL) to be applied on any found line. And doing this you achieve absolute flexibility.

Comment: @empo: Thanks. I love providing a complete solution as a single XPath expression. Not only can this be used in XQuery, too, but it is useful outside of XSLT and XQuery -- just with any XPath 2.0 stand-alone engine.

Comment: @LarsH: `find()` is not a standard function. One can define such a function (as @Michael Kay did) and this is solely a matter of design approach. Personally, I prefer passing a function as a parameter (a la FXSL) so that this HOF could be most flexible and reusable.

Comment: @Dimitre: ah, ok, I missed that `find()` was not a standard function. At first I wondered why @Michael Kay didn't use `index-of()`... then I realized that the latter looks for items that are *equal* to the arg, whereas we need items that *contain* the arg. Which helps me see why you want to be able to pass of function, to make it more general.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="executionId" select="70"/>
    <xsl:param name="executionEnd" select="71"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="post70" select="tokenize(
            .,
            concat('Iteration number: ',$executionId,'\r?\n'),'m')[2]"/>

        <xsl:variable name="in7071" select="tokenize(
            $post70,
            concat('\r?\n.*Iteration number: ',$executionEnd,'\r?\n?'),'m')[1]"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$in7071"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces:

```
2011-06-15 15:38:07,187 - rest-Main - INFO - Test action: attachHostNic
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Run test: yes
2011-06-15 15:38:07,188 - rest-Main - INFO - Test positive: TRUE
```

Comment: +1 an interesting use of tokenize(). Note, your code assumes there is nothing between 'Iteration number: 70' and the end of the line... which may always be true. Good insight that we don't necessarily have to accept the OP's initial step of tokenizing the log file into a sequence of separate lines.

Comment: but can this be used as a generic solution? my log file has iterations from 1...350 for now. wont this work only for a couple of consecutives iterations?

Comment: @Eyal: if your input sample is correct enough to reflect your real use case, yes you can use it as a general solution, why not? Anyway, try it :))

Comment: @Eyal: the solution would have to be modified a little in order to handle many successive sections; but your original question did not say anything about that. It said you wanted to extract one section. I'm not saying you are wrong to ask for more than you originally asked for, but keep in mind that @empo fully solved your original request.

Comment: @LarsH @empo thank you i will test it and will reply shortly.

Comment: @Eyal welcome. If you are still in trouble and realize that your question is growing with requirements, just think of editing and expanding your question with the new details. We'll try to help you as much as possible.

Comment: @empo i took your advice and posted my full problem with the full xsl and input/output file. i hope this will be useful in the in solution. thanks